# Get the Ul li width and set it to the width of the ul li ul

Tags: javascript

Any way this is achievable? I would think something like:

```
IF( hover over element ) set child element width to element width .
```

But I don't really know how to start with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery:

```
$("#hover_elem").hover(function () {
    $(this)
        .children()
        .first()
        .width($(this).width());
});
```

You should probably start with a tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) in order to learn how to use JQuery.
JQuery is easier than Javascript but this will not help you to understand how Javascript works - and so knowing jQuery does not means that you know Javascript...

Comment: thanx John ill understand the grammar i think but what i would need is something like a lexikon where all written :P

Comment: // Edit : and dunno why but this code "  $("#navbar li").hover(function () {
      $(this).children().width($(this).width());
  });"  is expanding also the #navbbar li and i want it only to expand the children on the width of navbar li m i missing something ? Edit : and it expands them if i hover over them not if i  hover over the parent list item element